# Keep wordpress session while JW Player 5 is playing

Tags: wordpress, session, jwplayer

Any one know how to bind the playback status of jw player 5 as a browsing activity in order not to expire a wordpress session and keep the user logged in while watching long videos.

Thanks

Comment: Do you have an example of this ? I am not 100% what you are talking about here.

Comment: if a user is watching video, he will not browse around, his session will then expire (get logged out) I want to be able to keep the user logged in while watching videos and not be considered as idle. Thanks

Comment: Do you have a demo of this?

Comment: any wordpress site (and other sites) gets user logged out after idle time. Hoping there is a way not to be considered idle when watching a video.

Comment: Do you have an example of this that I can look at?

Comment: Where can I send you the account to login to my website. You can login and watch private livestream. after 30 minutes of playing the video not doing anything on site but watch, your session will expire and will be logged out. let me know where can I send you your login and password. thanks

Comment: Contact us here - http://www.jwplayer.com/contact-us/

Comment: I sent you login details to check it. Thanks